# Can't Eliminate Gap Below Image in DIV Using CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using CSS grid areas to create a two column page, the left column (product-image) will have images both horizontal and vertical and the right column (selection) is a long form. Here is an image:

[image]

Basically, I would like to get rid of the gap between the image and the product-info area. In other words, I want product-info and group-info to line up with the bottom of the image (either vertical or horizontal) The only way I can eliminate that space is through `object-fit:cover` but this then cuts out large parts of the image depending on the width of the browser. I've tried all object-fit options, but none seem to solve this issue. Is this just not fundamentally possible with CSS GRID? Seems so basic that I'm sure the issue is me. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
.full-container {
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 3fr;
padding:20px;
grid-template-areas: 
" product-image product-image selection "
" product-info group-info selection "
}


.product-image {
grid-area: product-image;
}

.product-image > img {
width: 100%;
}


.selection {
grid-area: selection;
padding-left: 30px;
}

.product-info {
grid-area: product-info;
padding-right:30px;
}

.group-info {
grid-area: group-info;
}
```

Comment: well a grid is like a table. unless you specifiy the row height, the height for every grid-cell going to be as high as the highest grid-cell within that row. Since your product info cell is higher then the image cells, the image will not be able to fit the entire space without being cropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want the second row to fill the height, so try adding this to `.full-container`

```
grid-auto-row: auto 1fr;
```

(That said, I think using grid here just adds more complexity while it can be achieved without it, try using flex instead)

Comment: grid-auto-rows worked perfectly. Thank you. You're right on grid and I'll revisit the approach.